# How to change UIDatePicker Spacing between components

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

Im trying to add less spacing and remove the truncating effect on the day

Comment: if you are set the screen width it automatically adjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that. One might think of changing the **font size** as well, but you cannot do that either. The best deal (which I suggest) would be to change the date format (if that suits your requirement). Something like **Aug 21 2018** (only first three letters of months). This can be achieved by setting format as **MMM-dd-YYYY**

Comment: You can change the font size if you use a custom view on UIPickerView

Comment: Of-course. For that matter, there are number of libraries available. But my answer is focused on UIDatePicker only.